# Sum of unitary operators converges to projection operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

So let $\mathcal{H}$ be a hilbert space and $U$ is a unitary operator on $\mathcal{H}$. Let $I=\{v\in\mathcal{H}:U(v)=v\}$. Show that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^NU^n(v)\rightarrow Pv$ where $P:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ is the projection operator onto $I$. I don't know how to proceed with this problem. Can someone suggest hints as to how to do this.

Comment: What is $P$?? I assume it is a projection.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have updated my post.

Comment: From what I can see, $I$ is closed. So you can write $H=I \oplus I^{\perp}$. For $v \in H$, you can write $v=i+i^{\perp}$. Then $Uv=Ui+Ui^{\perp}=i+Ui^{\perp}$. This gives that $U^nv=i+U^ni^{\perp}$. All that needs to be shown is that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N U^n(i^{\perp}) \to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v \in I$ the result is trivial. Let $v \in I^{\perp}$ since the restriction of $\mathrm{Id} - U$ is bijective from $I^{\perp}$ to its image $\mathrm{Im}(\mathrm{Id}-U)$ Indeed it is injective : if $x \in I^{\perp}$, $(\mathrm{Id}-U)(x) = 0 \Rightarrow x \in I \Rightarrow x = 0$ it is also surjective because if $z \in \mathrm{Im}(\mathrm{Id}-U)$ then there is $y \in H$ such that $z = (\mathrm{Id} -U)(y)$. Since $(\mathrm{Id}-U)(P(y)) = 0$ setting $x = (\mathrm{Id}-P)(y)$ then $(\mathrm{Id}-U)(x) = z$. Let $v_n = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}U^n(v) \in I^\perp$ and $w_n = (I-U)(v_n)$, then $w_n = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(U^n(v) - U^{n+1}(v)\right) = \frac{1}{N}(U(v) - U^{N+1}(v)) \rightarrow 0$ because $||U|| = 1$. Setting $V$ the inverse of the restriction of $\mathrm{Id} - U$ on $I^\perp$, we have $v_n = V(w_n) \rightarrow 0$. The result is now verified for $v \in I^{\perp}$. Using $H = I + I ^{\perp}$ and the linearity of $P$ we have the result for all $v$.

Comment: Quick question. Why does $Im(Id-U)=I^\perp$, from the information given we can only conclude that   $Im(Id-U)\subseteq I^\perp$

Comment: I did not say that $Im(Id-U) = I^\perp$. I proved that the restriction of $Id-U$ on $I^\perp$ is bijective

Comment: But then how can you say there exists $w\in \mathcal{H}$ such that $v=w-U(w)$, since $v\in I^\perp$? Maybe I missed some part in your proof, but could you explain that part since you've only showed the map is bijective from $I^\perp$ to $Im(Id-U)$.

Comment: You are right. I was little bet fast in my typing but now I think I edit my answer and it must be clear now.

Comment: Thank Youem. Your edit clarifies things.

Comment: @Kroki how do you know that $V$, the inverse of $\mathrm{Id}-U$ is continuous?

Comment: $V$ is not bounded?

Comment: Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and let $T: X\rightarrow Y$ be linear, injective and bounded operators. Denote $R(T):= \left\{ Tx \ : \ x\in X\right\}$. Show that $T^{-1}: R(T)\rightarrow X $ is bounded iff $R(T)$ is closed. This is the fact I know. I don't see how to prove $\mathrm{Im}(\mathrm{Id}-U)$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I commented on Kroki's answer and came out with an alternative solution to avoid the problem using the inverse of $\mathrm{Id}-U$.
Here it is.

- It is easy to show that $I=\{x\in \mathcal{H}:Ux=x\}$ and $V=\{Ux-x:x\in\mathcal{H}\}$ are subspaces of $\mathcal{H}$.
- *Claim*: $I$ is the orthogonal complement of $V$ and $\mathcal{H}=I\oplus\overline{V}$.

*Proof*: First, we show that $I\subset V^\perp$. Take any $x\in I$, we have $\forall y\in H$,
$\left<x,y\right>=\left<Ux,Uy\right>=\left<x,Uy\right>$. Then,
$$\left<x,Uy-y\right>=\left<x,Uy\right>-\left<x,y\right>=0$$
This is true  $\forall Uy-y\in V$. Therefore, $I\subset V^\perp$.

Next, let's show that $V^\perp\subset I$. Take any $x\in V^\perp$, we have

\begin{align}
&\|Ux-x\|^2\\
&=\left<Ux-x,Ux-x\right>\\
&=\left<Ux,Ux-x\right>-\left<x,Ux-x\right>\\
&=\left<x,x-U^{-1}x\right>-0\\
&=\left<x,Uy-U^{-1}Uy\right>\\
&=\left<x,Uy-y\right>\\
&=0    
\end{align}

where in the third equality we have used the fact that $U^{-1}$ is also a unitary operator. And in the fourth equality, since $U$ is a bijection, $\exists y\in H$ such that $Uy=x$.
By the strict positivity axiom, we have $Ux-x=0\Rightarrow Ux=x$. So $V^\perp\subset I$. In conclusion, $I=V^\perp$.

- Lastly, we show that the sum converges for $u\in I$ and $v\in \overline{V}$, hence $\forall h\in \mathcal{H}$.

$I$ is clearly a closed subspace since $I$ is the kernel of the continuous linear map $S:H\to H$, $x\mapsto S(x)=Ux-x$. Since $V$ is a subspace, the linear hull of $V$, written as $\left<V\right>=V$. Thus, we have $\overline{V}=\overline{\left<V\right>}=(V^\perp)^\perp=I^\perp$. Hence, we have $H=I\oplus\overline{V}$.
In the case where $v\in I$, $\forall j\in\mathbb{N}, U^jv=v$ and $P_I(v)=v$. So $\forall j\in\mathbb{N}, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^jv=P_I(v)$. Hence, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^jv=v\to P_I(v)$ as $n\to\infty$.

In the case where $v\in V$, we have $v=Uw-w$ for some $w\in H$. Then
$$\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^jv=\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^j(Uw-w)=\frac1n(U^n w-w)$$
Then as $n\to \infty$
$$\frac1n\|U^nw-w\|\le \frac1n (\|U\|_{\mathrm{op}}^n+1)\|w\|=\frac2n\|w\|\to 0$$
Therefore, for $v\in V$, $\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^jv\to 0=P_I(v)$ as $n\to\infty$

Now if $v\in \overline{V}$, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $u\in V$ such that $\|v-u\|<\frac\epsilon 2$.   We have $$\left\|\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^j(v-u)\right\|\le \frac1n \|v-u\|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\|U\|^j_{\mathrm{op}}<\frac{\epsilon}2$$
And by our previous case, there exists $N$ such that when $n>N$,  We have $$\left\|\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^jv\right\|<\frac{\epsilon}2$$
Combining these two terms, we have
\begin{align}
 &\left\|\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^jv\right\|\\
 &=\left\|\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^j(v-u)+\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^ju\right\|\\
 &\le \left\|\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^j(v-u)\right\|+\left\|\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^ju\right\|\\
 &<\epsilon
\end{align}

Therefore, for $v\in\overline{V}$, $\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^jv\to 0=P_I(v)$ as $n\to\infty$.

Generally, any $h\in H$ can be written as a sum of $v_1\in I$ and $v_2\in \overline{V}$. It follows that as $n\to\infty$

$$\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^jh=\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^jv_1+\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}U^jv_2\to v_1=P_I(h)$$